# The "more" command fails to respond to automated input

Tags: bash

I tried to use herestrings to automate a script input and hence wanted to quit "more" of a file in it.

I've used:

```
$ echo q | more big_file.txt
$ more big_file.txt <<< q
$ yes q | more big_file.txt
$ echo -e "q\n" | more build.txt
```

but "more" command fails to quit.

Generally, the above mentioned input methods work for other commands in bash, but more seems to be exceptional,

Any idea what makes this a foul attempt?

NOTE: I don't want the data out of "more", but to quit "more" through an automated sequence is the target

Comment: so you're trying to get just the first few lines of the file, whatever fits on-screen? why not `head -20 big_file.txt` instead?

Comment: who said, first few lines? I want to quit more command that runs in another script

Comment: If it's not the first few lines, I have no idea either what you're trying to achieve there.

Comment: what else are you going to get. `more` shows one screen's worth of text at a time, and then you'd `q`uit it, so effectively you're only going to get those first X lines.

Comment: Sure. Why not. I mean, when I'm bored on rainy Sunday afternoons, I like to spawn a process or two and then send them mixed signals. Then I kill them and go for a round of guessing if the highest PID in the top is even or odd and what the closest prime is. So I'm not going to judge you if you've got weirder pastimes than I.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seriously though, whatever your misguided reason for wanting to keep `more` in the loop is, you're not going to have it quit voluntarily with anything else than terminal input. So:

- either you fake it. E.g. with `expect`
- or you have it quit nonvoluntary. With a signal. Try SIGQUIT, move to SIGTERM, fall down to SIGKILL as a last resort.

Comment: just because you don't need it or don't understand the need of it, doesn't mean, someone is misguided, It is very much necessary to accept EULA started by "more", running in a script while trying to accept the EULA through another script, to automate the installation by accepting the EULA, BTW, I know to use expect, and "KILL"ing signals, but wanted the know the crux of why "more" does't respond to input redirection, Do Answer, only If you can make "more" to take input redirection, else pls keep clam

Answer (score 1):

When it detects it's running on a terminal, `more` only takes its input from it.  This is so you can run things like:

```
$ cat multiple_files*.txt | more
```

(When it's *not* on a terminal, it doesn't even page, it degrades to behaving like `cat`.)